# Does the LMMS package on the Ubuntu repository supports VSTs?

Tags: official-repositories, lmms

I've installed LMMS through the Ubuntu repositories, and I noticed there's no "VeStiGe" instrument to allow the use of VSTs. I also haven't found any library on `/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lmms` named `libvestige.so` or anything similar.

I've Wine installed and even purged LMMS and reinstalled it in case I had installed it before Wine, but still couldn't find the instrument to import VSTs.

Does anybody know if the debian package of LMMS on the Ubuntu repositories is built with VST support? Would I need to install it from a third party repo to be able to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package in the official repositories doesn't have VST support. There are 3 alternatives to get it:

1. Download the version with VST support from third party repositories
2. Download the AppImage version from the official website
3. Download the Windows version from the official website and run it under Wine

I'm not very keen about adding third party repositories to my system, so I prefer options 2 and 3, the latter being apparently a bit more stable on my experience.